# listing all files and subdirectories using ant

Tags: ant

I am trying to create a `rpm` package using `ant task` for that I need to create `specfile` which will have all the file names in the following format

```
%attr(0755, root, root) %dir dir1
%attr(0755, root, root) %dir dir1/dir2
%attr(0755, root, root) %dir dir1/dir2/dir3

%attr(0500, root, root) dir1/file1
%attr(0500, root, root) dir1/dir2/file1
```

I have such directory structure created during my build process but using `ant` I am not able to list all the files and directories which I can then write into my `specfile`

following is what I have tried to list the files but it does not differentiate between files and directory , moreover I need some way to iterate over the list.

```
<fileset id="dist.contents" dir="${nativePackageDir}" includes="**"/>                                     |        
        <property name="prop.dist.contents" refid="dist.contents"/>                                               |  <target name="javaobject-library" depends="props">                                                             
        <echo>${prop.dist.contents}</echo>
```

Comment: Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449983/create-rpm-package-from-ant-script-under-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to [write in java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) an ant task implementation, to which you'll provide as parameters the input directory and the path of the specfile you want to be written.

I find it better and more manageable to have reusable ant tasks in java, instead of having gigantic ant xml files.

Answer (score 41):

```
<dirset id="dist.contents" dir="${nativePackageDir}" includes="*"/> 
<property name="prop.dist.contents" refid="dist.contents"/>
<echo>${prop.dist.contents}</echo>
```

Using **dirset** instead of **fileset** should fix your problem.

Comment: This should have been the selected answer.

Comment: This seems to just list children of a specific directory in a `;`-separated format. What if I want to print out the entire folder structure, recursively?